# Manual SQL Delete Query Causes Exception in Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have .net 4.5 MVC site using Entity Framework. There were some unnecessary test rows I deleted manually through a SQL workbench. When I reload the app, Im getting the following error below. I need to preserve the data.

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]
[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4515
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) +385
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more) +502
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read() +37
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +48

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.HandleReaderException(Exception e) +174
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +96
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +67
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +536
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   uptravi.Controllers.PagesController.Admin() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\actelion-IIS\development\admin\Controllers\PagesController.cs:27
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +217
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +231
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: And what is the query that you executed?

Comment: and what does the inner exception say? `See the inner exception for details.`

Comment: did you manually delete within a transaction? and have you not commited it, thus creating some sort of lock?

Comment: The query: DELETE FROM Table_Name WHERE ID = 'record_id'

Comment: Well the error is in your PageController.Admin method. I think you may have deleted data that is needed and now the admin method is yelling at you

Comment: Somehow this error went away on its own. It should be noted, the site is using load balanced servers which may have contributed to the erratic behavior.